# What do you call a parameter that is estimated from historical values?

Tags: estimation, parameterization

There are several methods to estimate parameters in a model (MLE, MAP, GMM). Does the process of estimating a parameter from historical data have a name?

Comment: Your title and body are asking different questions. The *process* is called "estimation". An *estimated parameter* is called an "estimate", or a "parameter estimate". The formula or algorithm by which you compute it is called an "estimator". E.g. I might estimate a population mean, $\mu$ by a sample mean, $\bar X$. Then $\bar X$ is called an estimator, and the value it takes on a given sample ($\bar x = 113.4$, say) is the estimate of $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

No. It doesn't have a special name, because parameters are always estimated from historical values. How else can they be *estimated*?